# How to get style.left

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know, I have a div element when the first load I set its attributes to `right:0` and `bottom:0`; I want to get its `style.left` but it return `NaN`. So how to get it or is there another way?

```
<div id="myDiv">Sample</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var setMe = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    setMe.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 670px;
        height: 370px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;");
    alert(setMe.style.left)
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you set `left` ? You have to set it first.

Comment: I know that jquery draggable can grab this , when we Inspect element and drag we will see left and top is assigned. but i don know how they assign that?

Answer (score 1):

Try it using [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle): ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gLjz/))

```
var setMe=document.getElementById("myDiv");

setMe.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;position:absolute;width:670px;height:370px;right:0;bottom:0;");

alert(window.getComputedStyle(setMe).left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Felement.offsetLeft) attribute.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">Sample</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var setMe=document.getElementById("myDiv");
    setMe.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;position:absolute;width:670px;height:370px;right:0;bottom:0;");
    alert(setMe.offsetLeft);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but offsetLeft is differ from style.left

Answer (score 0):

you have three options:

```
style property // --> Returns an object that represents the element's style attribute (setted when parsed)

getAttribute // --> returns the value of the named attribute on the specified element.

computedStyle // -->  gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.
```

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWm49/) (demo) for an example in every one.

Also:

- [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)
- [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute)
- [computedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.getComputedStyle)